# How to open window's process using angular 2

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying below code to open windows process in angular 2

```
<button onclick="window.open('file:///C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe')">Calculator</button>
```

And I am getting the error like :
    Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe

Can someone suggest any other solution to open process using angular 2?

Comment: This question is not related to Angular in any way. You do it the same way as without Angular.

Comment: The browser won't allow you access to windows system files as it would be a security issue. Maybe look into something like Electron for this.

Comment: The above snippet yes off course is a javascript.But as I was getting 'Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe' this error so is there anything which has been already taken care in angular packages which could support access to browser to open process?